# From address different from the SMTP address sent through Outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, smtp

I have a web-only-based email address I want to use when writing from Outlook 2007 but the web-based email address doesn't allow SMTP connections.

In Outlook, I can configure an account that has my web-based email address as the REPLY-TO address, However, Outlook still sends the email FROM whichever SMTP server I send it through.

So effectively I cannot send an email from within Outlook 2007 that really appears to be sent from my web-based email address. I want the people I write to to only see the web-based email address I'm using/writing from.

I can manually invoke/display the "FROM" field, and enter my web-based email address there, however Outlook appears to ignore that and still list the SMTP account email address as the FROM address once the email is sent

I am running Windows XP and Outlook 2007 (without Exchange).

I used to be a Eudora Pro user, and Eudora happily sent emails via any legit SMTP server (with my appropriate login credentials) *while* listing the From address as anything I chose. In other words, it did not differentiate between the Reply-To and the From address.

However, Outlook does. While Outlook happily accepts any Reply-To email address I put into the account settings, it appears to stubbornly insist on the From address being whatever smtp server (address) I sent it through.

---

I do have numerous accounts set up within one PST, and have numerous smpt servers, as they correspond to the email accounts.

However, the one account I am asking about does not allow SMTP through its servers. Thus, when writing 'from' me@web-based-email-account.com, I have to use a different account's smtp server to send. This then seems to force Outlook to list that SMTP server account as the "From" address, while it lists the web-based account address as the 'reply-to' address. A recipient of that email then sees both the 'from' address and the 'reply-to' address. And I would like for them to only see the 'reply-to', that is, the web-based email address.

Is there a way to make that happen? Eudora Pro used to do it with no problems.

Comment: Please avoid posting a personal e-mail address.  All replies/comments should appear here

Answer (score 1):

In the Mail account settings you should be able to specify a specific SMTP server.  Have you done that?

As you noted some ISPs may require additional configuration if you are connecting on a different network.  This may mean authentication is required.  Image below shows a common ISP in Canada.  Outlook will alos allow you to setup multiple accounts using the same PST and then you set the one you want as default

[image: Outlook Account Settings]